# Find Top 1 best matching string in SQL server

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005, sql-like

I have a table '**MyTable**' which has some business logics. This table has a column called **Expression** which has a string built using other columns. 
My query is

```
Select Value from MyTable where @Parameters_Built like Expression
```

The variable @Parameters_Built is built from Input parameters by Concatenating all together.

In my current scenario,

```
@Parameteres_Built='1|2|Computer IT/Game Design &amp; Dev (BS)|0|1011A|1|0|'

Below are the expressions
---------------------
%%|%%|%%|0|%%|%%|0|
---------------------
1|2|%%|0|%%|%%|0|
---------------------
1|%%|%%|0|%%|%%|0|
---------------------
```

So my above query returns true for all the three rows. But It should return only the second row (Maximum match).

I just don't need a solution with fix for this scenario. It's just a example. I need a solution like choosing the best match. Any idea?

Comment: So you mean it should return the row that uses the least number of % variables i.e. the quality of the match?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness Wow, yeah. Good idea. Do you have Query to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. Can you not break the | delimited string and store the various values in their own database columns?

Comment: it is possible, it's only a matter whatever it can be done simply or not :)

Comment: Actually this value is built from the separate columns. My idea is, we can replace % with empty string and find the length of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Select top 1 * from MyTable 
where @Parameters_Built like Expression
order by len(Expression)-len(replace(Expression,'%',''))
```

- this orders the results by the number of non-`%` characters in expression.

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7067a/6).

Comment: @Mark - Great, it worked thanks. Also thanks to tomasmcguinness for initiating the idea.